# How to convert a string yyyy-mm-dd to month name?

Tags: date, jasper-reports

I have a string file `FECHA EMISION="2018-03-02"`. I want it to display as "Marzo" (March in Spanish/Italian).

I have to convert `$F{FECHA EMISION}.substring(5,7)` in integer, but I don´t know how convert the result 02 to the related month.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this expression to a textField:

```
DATEFORMAT(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse($F{FECHA EMISION}), "MMMMM")
```

Comment: I'm surprise the you don't suggest the use of pattern (that will keep original data if you export to eg excel), so I have posted a competing answer :P

Comment: Why keep the date when it was a string originally?

Comment: Because it's incorrectly a String, it should have been a Date :), anyway not much difference.

Comment: This option work correctly. Thanks

Comment: But i want to print "MARZO", i mean, the option before give me marzo like a date. I have to convert it to string and then apply touppercase() but i don´t know the nomenclature for this

Comment: The correct expression is UPPER(DATEFORMAT(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse($F{FECHA EMISION}), "MMMMM")). It shows MARZO.

Comment: Once you have the month name you are in control of its formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object and then apply a pattern (pattern will allow you to export original data to e.g. excel while displaying it as you like)

To apply a pattern you will need to transform the String into a Date object

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse($F{FECHA EMISION})
```

The pattern is `MMMM` see [Date and Time Patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

So the final jrxml will be

```
<textField pattern="MMMM">
   <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse($F{FECHA EMISION})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

> Note: In JasperSoft Studio pattern is a property of the textField, hence you can indicate this directly in Studio.